# Jenkins Error "Microsoft Excel cannot access the file"

Tags: jenkins

I am using jenkins to run a .bat file that is in location

```
C:\Users\foo\Desktop\xxx.bat
```

which internally

1. copies from another machine an excel
2. calls a vbs script found in D:

```
D:\foo\Newtask.vbs
```

that opens a file:

```
C:\Users\foo\Desktop\xxx\xxx\xxx\New.xlsm
```

The error I am getting is

1. For the first excel: `The system cannot find the path specified`
2. For the second New.xlsm:

```
D:\foo\Newtask.vbs(14, 1) Microsoft Excel: Microsoft Excel cannot access the file 'C:\Users\foo\Desktop\xxx\xxx\xxx\New.xlsm'. There are several possible reasons:

 The file name or path does not exist.
 The file is being used by another program.
 The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook
```

I find it odd that jenkins can access and run .bat in foo user's directory while it cannot find `C:\Users\foo\Desktop\xxx\xxx\xxx\New.xlsm` --> I checked it exists.

When running the .bat manually i have no problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe the user Jenkins runs as does not have permission to access that Excel file? Or the step to copy the Excel file didn't work within Jenkins.

Comment: Thanks u for your answer! The build of jenkins runs as SYSTEM, so i guess it is not a matter of permissions. The original .bat file was created by foo user and jenkins runs it...

Comment: I am having same problem where I am opening excel in powershell for conversion. The command runs fine when run independently but gives me same error when run through jenkins. I will appreciate if anybody knows why this happens.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Solution from this page worked https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-support-blog/error-8216-microsoft-office-excel-cannot-access-the-file-8217/ba-p/317477

...x64: Create the following directory:
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop

x86: Create the following directory:
C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).